# ionic infinite scrolling with ionic and php data

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and working with project where I need to use infinite scrolling.  I have searched for it but I didn't get satisfied answer. All solutions has static data which I don't want.  I want to data from php file which is in server.

**Controller**

```
.controller('MylistCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicLoading, $state, myService) {
        $scope.items = {};
        myService.getMyTime('37.0000', '35.3213', '2', '3', '2015').then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.items = response;
        });
    })

.factory('myService', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
            getMyTime: function (lat,lng,gmt,method,year) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    url: base_url + 'mylist.php',
                    method: "GET",
                    params: {lat: lat, lng: lng, GMT: gmt, Method: method, Year: year},
                }).success(function (response, status) {
                    if (typeof response.data == 'object') {
                        deferred.resolve(response.data);
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject(response.data);
                    }
                }).error(function () {
                    deferred.reject(response.data);
                })
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-view class="full-bg>
<ion-content>
    <ion-list >
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-30 month">
                    <div class="day"> 
                        <h1>{{item.day}}</h1>
                        <h2>{{item.month}}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="year">{{item.year}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-45 time">{{item.Fajr}}</div>
                <div class="col col-25 alarm-icon"><i class="icon ion-ios-alarm"></i><i class="icon ion-checkmark-round"></i></div>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
   <ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="1%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using [Ionic Infinite Scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/) directive in your view. Include it. And $http service, returns a promise by default. Why are you creating a new defer object?

Comment: I have already implemented it there but forget to put the code, please look at the edited code

Comment: I am new to Ionic and I don't about services, I have picked from the demo and made some modifications in it !!

Comment: I have already tried the link which you have provided but I don't know what is useItems(items); in this tutorial !!?

Comment: It is an example! In your case you should concat the result to `items`. 

`$scope.items.concat(response.data)`